# Web3Modal Injected Provider not showing in options

Tags: javascript, web3js

I have a problem using Web3Modal, the connect panel doesn't show the metamask provider.
[image]

Here is the code:

```
const providerOptions = {
        injected: {
          display: {
            logo: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
            name: 'Metamask',
            description: 'Connect with the provider in your Browser',
          },
          package: null,
        },
          walletconnect: {
            package: WalletConnectProvider,
            options: {
              infuraId: "INFURA_ID" 
            }
          },
            coinbasewallet: {
            package: CoinbaseWalletSDK, 
            options: {
              appName: "My Awesome App",
              infuraId: "INFURA_ID"
            }
          }
        };

        const web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
          network: "mainnet", // optional
          cacheProvider: false, // optional
          disableInjectedProvider: true,
          providerOptions // required
        });
        const provider = await web3Modal.connect();
```

That's really weird cause it seems that the injected provider is always included by default ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try taking out the:

```
disableInjectedProvider: true,
```

?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You should set your disableInjectedProvider to false, not true.

> By default is set to false and Web3Modal always displays
> InjectedProvider as an option to the user if available. However you
> can disable it as an optional flag if you desire:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3modal